# Convert png to svg in R?

Tags: r

Is there a convenient way to convert a `.png` to `.svg` using o*nly base R or [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html)* functions?

Currently I'm using an external (point and click) program to convert images. Would be very handy to be able to do so in R

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the `image_convert` function from the `magick` package. Check the [package description](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/index.html) and the ['Converting formats' section from the package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html#converting_formats).

Actually it is using ['ImageMagick'](https://imagemagick.org/index.php), an open-source image processing library worth a look itself.

#### Example code

```
library(magick)
my_image <- image_read("image.png")
my_svg <- image_convert(my_image, format="svg")
image_write(my_svg, "image.svg")

dir()
[1] "image.png"   "image.svg"
```